# Почему Spark Core тормозит?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

При работе только с spark sql запросы на базу обрабатываются очень быстро, но при подключении JavaPairJDD он начинает тормозить.

Я хотел бы узнать, есть ли возможность ускорить обработку данных или же как-то улучшить код для того чтобы он не зависал?

Вот запуск без JavaPairRDD

```
collectAsList at StackOverFlow.java:56, took 0.883860 s
```

А вот с JavaPairRDD

```
collectAsMap at StackOverFlow.java:61, took 128.340516 s
```

А вот сам Код

```
public List<Order> getAllWithoutPairRDD(Optional<String> search, Optional<Integer> size) {

    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().config(config).getOrCreate();

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.setProperty("partitionColumn", "id");
    properties.setProperty("fetchsize", "1000");
    properties.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    properties.setProperty("user", "postgres");
    properties.setProperty("password", "password");

    Dataset<Row> jdbc = session.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/orders"
            , "orders"
            , "id"
            , 1L
            , 60000000L
            , 100
            , properties
    );
    Dataset<Row> ordersData = jdbc.select(col("*")).where(col("city_id").equalTo(3L)).limit(size.orElse(1));
    JavaPairRDD<Timestamp, Integer> analyticPairRDD = ordersData.toJavaRDD().mapToPair((PairFunction<Row, Timestamp, Integer>) row -> new Tuple2<Timestamp, Integer>((Timestamp) row.get(0), 1));

    JavaPairRDD<Timestamp,Integer> result = analyticPairRDD.groupByKey().mapValues(Iterables::size);
    return ordersData.as(orderEncoder).collectAsList();
}

public Map<Timestamp, Integer> getAllWithPairRDD(Optional<String> search, Optional<Integer> size) {

    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().config(config).getOrCreate();

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.setProperty("partitionColumn", "id");
    properties.setProperty("fetchsize", "1000");
    properties.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    properties.setProperty("user", "postgres");
    properties.setProperty("password", "password");

    Dataset<Row> jdbc = session.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/orders"
            , "orders"
            , "id"
            , 1L
            , 60000000L
            , 100
            , properties
    );
    Dataset<Row> ordersData = jdbc.select(col("operation_date")).where(col("city_id").equalTo(3L)).limit(size.orElse(1));
    JavaPairRDD<Timestamp, Integer> analyticPairRDD = ordersData.toJavaRDD().mapToPair((PairFunction<Row, Timestamp, Integer>) row -> new Tuple2<Timestamp, Integer>((Timestamp) row.get(0), 1));

    JavaPairRDD<Timestamp,Integer> result = analyticPairRDD.groupByKey().mapValues(Iterables::size);
    return result.collectAsMap();
}
```

---

```
@Bean
public SparkConf sparkConf() {
    return new SparkConf()
            .setAppName(appName)
            .setMaster(masterUri)
            .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
            .set("spark.executor.cores", "10")
            .set("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "1g")
            .set("spark.driver.cores", "10")
            .set("spark.driver.memory", "3g")
            .set("spark.yarn.am.memory", "2g")
            .set("spark.yarn.am.cores", "4")
            .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1000")
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скорее всего он тормозит из-за того, что данные должны быть раскиданы по экзекуторам - pair RDD требует раскидывания данных по ключу, и это может быть медленным процессом, конечно это зависит от объема данных...

Но в данном случае я не вижу нужды использовать RDD - лучше использовать функции Spark SQL, или вообще работать в чистом SQL, выполняя все нужные аггрегации - тогда спарк сам оптимизует выполнение, в отличии от RDD где это не делается.

P.S. есть много других проблем в этом случае:

1. запрос к базе не обязательно будет выполнятся в параллель, тогда данные будут вытаскиваться только одним экзекутором
2. `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` установлен в слишком большое число - `1000` - это означает что данные будут раскиданы по 1000 разделов (если будет shuffle), и для каждого будет создан таск, который должен быть выполнен, а при 10 ядрах на экзекуторе, это будет 100 итераций.  Обычно этот параметр устанавливается в 1 или 2 умножить на полное количество ядер на экзекуторах

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я еще хотел спросить у вас на счет способа подключения к hadoop через idea если не трудно), вот ссылка на вопрос (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197695/Как-с-помощью-spark-подключиться-к-hadoop-через-intellij-idea)

Comment: я к сожалению работал с Hadoop очень давно, и под рукой у меня его нет.  Обычно были проблемы с правами доступа и т.п. - в ошибке я вижу ссылки на локальный файл (`file://`) - но я не вижу его упоминания в спарковой джобе, так что скорее что-то с настройками